# Random String Generator that does not repeat in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, autoload

I created this function in my laravel controller.

```
function incrementalHash($len = 5){
    $charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $base = strlen($charset);
    $result = '';

    $now = explode(' ', microtime())[1];
    while ($now >= $base){
        $i = $now % $base;
        $result = $charset[$i] . $result;
        $now /= $base;
    }
    return substr($result, -5);
}
```

then I have a function to insert something in the database. this function uses the above function. but every time I use it I get the same result from above function. I tried `composer dump-autoload` and the result changes. I wonder what is happening? why this method always returns the same result. how can I use this method and not receive the same result without dumping autoload? here is my controller:

```
public function add_user_create()
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->user_id = Request()->input('user_id');
    $user->user_name = Request()->input('user_name');
    $user->fcm = Request()->input('fcm');
    $user->email = Request()->input('email');
    $user->token = Request()->input('token');
    $user->profile_pic = Request()->input('profile_pic');
    $user->api_token = str_random(60);
    $user->ref_ID = $this->incrementalHash(4);
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: ps. i've tried to make my method as static but it didn't work

Comment: try `$random = str_random(40);`

Comment: use str_random() laravel helper function

Comment: @kenken9999 I know str_random(4) method works. but I like to know why this is happening and how can I use my method? I also don't want upper case letters in my random string

Comment: strtolower(str_random(4)), where you save the function ?

Comment: Because `$now` is always > then `$base`: https://3v4l.org/JWWC8 - Not sure what your trying to do there.

Comment: Take a peek at https://hashids.org/php/ :)

Comment: where is the $len

Comment: Could always use [base_convert](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) for example, https://3v4l.org/dv4Ko

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use what Laravel provides to generate a random string. like: `strtolower(str_random(4))` as mentioned by @kenken9999

However, Here is **why I think** it gave same result for you:

I executed your function multiple times and these are the outputs:

```
becpy
becqa
becqd
becqd
becqe
```

I think when you checked them they just happend to be same and when you did `composer dump-autoload` you happened to see a different output.

Let me know If I am wrong.

Comment: > "Random String Generator **that does not repeat** in laravel controller"

Answer (score 1):

Did you call this function many times during a very short time? Then I believe the issue is `microtime()`. This function returns a string separated by a space. The first part is the fractional part of seconds, the second part is the integral part.

Thus, if the function is called during the same second, `$now` should be the same, based on which `$result` will not change.
Further, if the function is called during a short time (let's say several seconds), `$now` would be similar (`1283846202` and `1283846203` for example). In this case, only the right part of `$result` would vary.